# Преобразовать строку в дату. mySQL

Tags: mysql

Получаю котировки валют в XML. Дата котировки передается в таком формате:

```
Wed, 9 Oct 2019 00:00:01 GMT
```

Можно как-то занести это значение в поле типа DATETIME или TIMESTAMP таблицы БД?

Вроде как работает этот способ преобразования:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Wed, 9 Oct 2019 00:00:01 GMT','%W, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Но в БД занести возвращаемое значение не получается:

```
Ошибка SQL (1292): Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'Wed, 9 Oct 2019 00:00:01 GMT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так там же еще `GMT` в строке стоит

установить в поле форматированную дату

```
UPDATE [table] SET [field] = STR_TO_DATE('Wed, 9 Oct 2019 00:00:01 GMT','%W, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s GMT')
```

установить в поле UNIX_TIMESTAMP:

```
UPDATE [table] SET [field] = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Wed, 9 Oct 2019 00:00:01 GMT','%W, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s GMT'))
```

Comment: благодарю, работает.